# Can I use one travel converter for UK mains type G for multiple type A socketed appliances?

Tags: usa, uk, power

I am going to travel to the UK and wonder if I can use one travel adapter with my 4-way (type A) power strip or will I need to use multiple power adapters? Some friends of mine recommend using a native type G 4-way power strip with multiple adapters instead of just one adapter into my own 4-way power strip. Is it possible?

Comment: just pin configuration

Comment: Are you talking about plug adaptor or voltage adaptor? Or both?

Comment: I'm guessing just a plug adapter if she says just pin config

Answer (score 4):

You can use a US-style "type A" power strip in the UK, so long as some conditions are met:

1. It must not have any components such as lamps or meters which are sensitive to the line voltage.  Obviously the power strip will be seeing 220V instead of 120V, and some power strips do have lamps to indicate power being applied which could pose a problem if used with 220V.
2. If it is a surge protector, it must not be a "fancy" one which actively regulates voltage (this is not very common, but they're sometimes used for home entertainment systems).
3. Technically, its wiring, plugs, and outlets need to be rated for 220V, not just 110V.  The outside of the main lead should be stamped with max voltage, and the plug probably will be too.  You will often find that the plug is labeled 120V simply because it is a US-style plug (though a few places use these plugs with 220V).
4. Legally, there are rules in the UK about extension cords and power strips, and they are pretty stringent and different from the rules in the US.  Understanding these rules would be very important if you plan to use this setup in a non-residential setting, or for an extended period of time.

Now, all that said: it will probably work.  If the power strip is the super-cheap and simple kind with no "features," it will definitely work.

I've done similar when travelling, using a simple three-outlet brick-style adapter with no cord at all.  But over time I've acquired a few cords with different plugs, so much of the time I don't actually need to rely on adapters anymore.  For example, a USB phone charger with UK-style plug is cheap, as are detachable cords for computers, camera battery chargers, etc.